# In these cases, the Scala value class will be "boxed", right?

Tags: scala, memory-management

If I have this value class:

```
class ActionId(val value: Int) extends AnyVal
```

Then, in all the examples below, an object will be allocated for the value class? (It'll be "boxed" — it will *not* simply be unwrapped to a plain 32 bit integer, right?)

1. A function that returns a value class — the value class escapes the scope and will hence be "boxed"?

   ```
   def someFunction(): ActionId = {
     ...
     return ActionId(123)
   }
   ```
2. A function that returns *an object with a value class member* — the value class escapes the scope and will hence be "boxed"?

   ```
   case class Post(id: ActionId, ...) { ... }

   def someFunction(): Post = {
     ...
     val somePost = Post(ActionId(123), ...) // ActionId will be "boxed", right?
     return somePost
   }
   ```
3. Even if *the object with a value class member* is *not* returned (doesn't really escape the scope), the value class will still be "boxed", when it is used as a member of another class (as a field in the `Post` class, in this example)?

   ```
   def anotherFunction() {
     ...
     val somePost = Post(ActionId(123), ...) // "Boxed" here too, right?

     // ... do something with somePost

     // But don't:  return somePost

     // However some *other* similar functions *do* return `somePost` — so
     // class `Post` must be able to box the ActionId? Hence it's boxed (above)?
   }
   ```

Related to this is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11279421/694469), which says that *when the value class doesn't escape the scope*, it's effectively being inlined. It refers to Scala Improvement Process document [SIP-15](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) for more details. However as far as I can tell SIP-15 actually doesn't mention that a value class instance that escapes the scope will be "boxed". But I think it seems reasonable that it would have to be "boxed". (Why doesn't the SIP explicitly state that it will be boxed if it escapes?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

None of your examples result in boxing. Value classes are only boxed with generics, with arrays, and when typed as a superclass/trait (e.g. Any/AnyVal)

They're boxed with generics because otherwise you can't distinguish them from the value (and primitives need a box anyway).  Same deal with Any, and other superclasses/traits need a box or the type relationship is wrong.

They're boxed with arrays because arrays need to know the type of the contents, but the JVM doesn't understand the concept of a "value type".  So you'd end up with an array that said it was the type being boxed, but which Scala was pretending was an array of the value type; a decision was made (based on previous issues with Array when it wasn't just a plain Java/JVM array) that this would lead to too many subtle bugs and corner cases.

Here's an example of the three ways to get boxing:

```
trait Q extends Any {}
class X(val x: String) extends AnyVal with Q {}

// Array
val a = Array(new X("salmon"))   // boxed

// Generic
val b = Option(new X("minnow"))  // boxed

// Upcast
val c = (new X("perch"): Any)    // boxed
val d = (new X("cod"): AnyVal)   // boxed
val e = (new X("herring"): Q)    // boxed
```

Everything else--passing around through various functions, etc.--doesn't require boxing, including all of your examples.

Arrays are a bit of a special case because you can store the primitives and pull them out again as value classes with zero bytecode overhead, but a lot of syntactic overhead:

```
class Y(val repr: String) extends AnyVal {}
val y1 = new Y("apple")    // unboxed
val y2 = new Y("orange")   // unboxed
val ys: Array[String] = Array(y1.repr, y2.repr)   // no overhead
val y3 = new Y(ys(0))      // no overhead
```

Comment: Can you imagine library support to mitigate the syntactic overhead when dealing with arrays?

Comment: @ziggystar - Well, right now everything that reduces the syntactic overhead increases the bytecode overhead.  So it's a difficult game to play.  When it matters, you can have a value class that wraps the array and does the work for you (with very minimal syntactic overhead), but I am not sure of a way to make a trivial factory that given a value class produces the corresponding array value class.  Macros will eventually get there, I suppose.

Comment: @RexKerr so does this mean that there are no value classes inside data structures? In other words, List, Map, etc will always instantiate the boxed class?

Comment: @ms-tg - Yes, that's right.  Scala errs on the side of keeping the type identifiable at runtime.  Otherwise you could put the boxed item into a list, take it out unboxed, and be none the wiser.  Or, worse yet, you could put in Feet and take it out as Meters.

Comment: @RexKerr I think we'd assumed that List[Feet] would store the doubles in the most efficient way, since at it api boundary it knows it's Feet?

Comment: @ms-tg - That works until you cast it to `List[Any]`, and then `match { case d: Double => ...}`.  And you _are_ supposed to be able to safely do that.

Answer (score 12):

In all three cases there will be no boxing at all.

It's quite easy to check by your self:

```
class ActionId(val value: Int) extends AnyVal
object Foo {
  def someFunction(): ActionId = {
    new ActionId(123)
  }
}
```

Now lets run scalac, and we will have a bunch of class files (files with bytecode). The one that we need is Foo\$.

```
» javap Foo\$ 
Compiled from "Boxing.scala"
public final class Foo$ extends java.lang.Object{
    public static final Foo$ MODULE$;
    public static {};
    public int someFunction();
}
```

As you can see, even if value class leaks from function generally it wouldn't be boxed.

```
case class Post(id: ActionId, notion: String)

object Foo2 {
  def someFunction(): Post = {
    Post(new ActionId(123), "So ActionID will be boxed?")
  } 
}
```

scalac => javap:

```
» javap Post  
Compiled from "Boxing.scala"
public class Post extends java.lang.Object implements scala.Product,scala.Serializable{
    public static scala.Function1 tupled();
    public static scala.Function1 curried();
    public int id();
    public java.lang.String notion();
    public Post copy(int, java.lang.String);
    public int copy$default$1();
    public java.lang.String copy$default$2();
    public java.lang.String productPrefix();
    public int productArity();
    public java.lang.Object productElement(int);
    public scala.collection.Iterator productIterator();
    public boolean canEqual(java.lang.Object);
    public int hashCode();
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    public Post(int, java.lang.String);
}
```

As you can see id here represented as plain int (e.g. third method).

Finally, will value class boxed if the object with a value class member is not returned (doesn't really escape the scope)?

```
case class Post(id: ActionId, notion: String)

object Foo3 {
  def anotherFunction(): Unit {
    val post = Post(new ActionId(123), "Will be boxed?")
  } 
}
```

If we look closely at bytecode of the method, here is what we will see:

```
Code:
   Stack=4, Locals=2, Args_size=1
   0:   new #15; //class Post
   3:   dup
   4:   bipush  123
   6:   ldc #17; //String Will be boxed?
   8:   invokespecial   #20; //Method Post."<init>":(ILjava/lang/String;)V
   11:  astore_1
   12:  return
  LocalVariableTable: 
   Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
   0      13      0    this       LFoo3$;
   12      0      1    post       LPost;
```

There is no boxing of int in ActionId. If it would box you would see something like this one:

```
Code:
   Stack=5, Locals=2, Args_size=1
   0:   new #15; //class Post
   3:   dup
   4:   new #17; //class ActionId
   7:   dup
   8:   bipush  123
   10:  invokespecial   #20; //Method ActionId."<init>":(I)V
   13:  ldc #22; //String Will be boxed?
   15:  invokespecial   #25; //Method Post."<init>":(LActionId;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   18:  astore_1
   19:  return
  LocalVariableTable: 
   Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
   0      20      0    this       LFoo3$;
   19      0      1    post       LPost;
```

You see, the difference is `bipush  123` versus

```
   4:   new #17; //class ActionId
   7:   dup
   8:   bipush  123
   10:  invokespecial   #20; //Method ActionId."<init>":(I)V
```

Comment: Can you give an example when a value class will box?

Comment: @ziggystar it will be boxed if one will place value class into collection, e.g. List

Answer (score 3):

With some implicit casts it is actually possible to get around the array-issue without the syntactic required by rex-kerr. I used it in conjunction with [How to reduce the number of objects created in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646243/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-objects-created-in-scala#answer-13646537)

Y.scala:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

class Y(val repr: String) extends AnyVal {}
object Y {
    implicit def stringToY (v:String) = new Y(v)
    implicit def yToString (v:Y) = v.repr
}
```

Main file:

```
import Y._

val y1 = new Y("apple")    // unboxed
val y2 = new Y("orange")   // unboxed
val ys: Array[String] = Array(y1, y2)   // Implicit cast
val y3:Y = ys(0)
```

Comment: Isn't `String` a poor choice in that it is technically a reference type? IOW, wouldn't the example be far more specific and relevant if `Int` (or `Byte`, `Short`, `Long`, etc.) were used instead?