# How to avoid implicit type conversion when pass varargs in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion, variadic-functions

I wrote a function like this:

```
def a (params:Any*) = {
    val clazzes = params.map(_.getClass)
    ...
}
```

But when I pass in a param with type of Scala Long, it is automatically converted to `java.lang.Long` 
Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: No, a couple of days ago there was a similar problem in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288212/java-lang-integer-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-byte-error-with-any-type-in-scala/25288476#25288476), the compiler defaults to primitive types when dealing with boxed types, being `Any` in this case it defaults to java primitives. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the default implicit conversion that is defined in the Predef:

```
import Predef.{long2Long=>_,println}

object Test{

  val tL : java.lang.Long = 1L

}
```

You'll then get a type error :

```
Error:(26, 29) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.Long(1L)
 required: java.lang.Long
  val tL : java.lang.Long = 1L
                        ^
```

But, in your case your parameters are getting boxed as an Any* (a wrapped array). 
The runtime boxed representation of a scala long is java.lang.Long. This isn't an implicit conversion, so it isn't going to be suppressed.

```
import Predef.{long2Long=>_,println}

object Test extends App{

   def a(params: Any*) = {
    for(p<-params) yield(p.getClass)
  }

  println(a(1L))

}
```

Output:

```
ArrayBuffer(class java.lang.Long)
```

Its possible you want to write generic code that avoids boxing. If thats the case you'll need to look into specialization.